# How to convert Base64 into BitmapImage and save it in Subforlder in Project

Tags: winrt-xaml

I need to retrieve image with webService which converted it into base64 
and I need to convert this base64 into BitmapImage and save it into the folder which I added into project

I have these questions:

1) Do I have to convert Base64String into Stream and create a bitmapImage with it?

Can this BAse64 string be used as byte for creating bitmapImage without converting it to Buffer?

2) How to save the bitmapImage in the specific Folder after conversion from Base64 to buffer?

The problem:
no error and no image is saved!

I dont seems to be able to save it. Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
public async Task Base64StringToBitmapTask(string Base64source,string Filenm)
 {

  var ims = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();    

  var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64source);
  var dataWriter = new DataWriter(ims);        
  dataWriter.WriteBytes(bytes);         
  await dataWriter.StoreAsync();        
  ims.Seek(0);

  var bm = new BitmapImage();
  bm.SetSource(ims);         

  byte[] pixeBuffer = null;

  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
      WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bm.PixelWidth,bm.PixelHeight);
       await wb.SetSourceAsync(ims);

      Stream s1 = wb.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
       s1.CopyTo(ms);

       pixeBuffer = ms.ToArray();

     }
  await InsertImageInFolder(pixeBuffer, Filenm);

 }

private async Task InsertImageInFolder(byte[] buffer, string filename)
 {


   IBuffer Ibr = buffer.AsBuffer();

   StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

   //-1-- Get the folder added into the Project


   StorageFolder subfolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("ms-appx:///ProductImages");


  //-2---- create a file in this folder 

  await subfolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

  StorageFile  sampleFile = await subfolder.GetFileAsync(filename);


  await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(sampleFile, Ibr);         

}
```

Comment: If you have the image bytes saved as a base64 string, why do you need to put it into a `WriteableBitmap`? Why can't you just save it with the proper filename and extension? Do you need to encode it? If so, use a `BitmapEncoder`.

Comment: I want to save the image file into a folder call ProductImages which I added to the project. 1st, I convert the base64 into BitmapImage.I need its buffer for the InsertImageInFolder(). I pass in the filename as xxxx.jpg. Can you show me what I need to do. Thanks

Comment: I realize that you need the buffer, but the base64 should already be the base64 encoding of its buffer. Why can you not just write out `bytes`? Unless you are asking what needs to be done in `InsertImageInFolder` to write it out to a file?

Comment: I am not familiar with base64, image and file operation logic. I just updated my code. Can u help to correct my logic as I dont know what comes first or later.

Comment: base64 is just a way to encode a byte array into a string of alphanumeric characters. Based on where you are getting it from, it likely just represents the bytes of your image. I think I noticed a problem in your file writing logic though: await `StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("ms-appx:///ProductImages");` should just say `await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("ProductImages");`

Comment: Still not solved. Encountered infinite loop at Stream s1 = wb.PixelBuffer.AsStream() after making correct changes for WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(200,200); wb.SetSource(ims) and await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("ProductImages")

Comment: Infinite loop? Where? What was the exception thrown, a StackOverflow? Or did it just repeatedly hit your breakpoints?